Identify this film where boy chooses his life over his mothers in front of a ghost
Genre - horror
Story - A boys journey throughout a road is shown. Where he faces different things. A dog(May be German Shepard ) which attacks him and many other weird things. The main plot is about a man who give him a ride but turned out to be a ghost who met an accident on the same road and became ghost. He ask him to give his soul to him or his mothers soul. He chooses to give his mothers soul (he hates her because of a childhood incident when she slaps her when he refuse to go to giant wheel in amusement park). After that he realizes that he loves his mother and goes to the hospital where her mother is admitted. I think there is also some fight between the ghost and boy. In the end mother and son both survive.
Broadcasting Channel - MGM (I watched it on MGM in India)
I didn't know any other details other than these. Its appears to be of early 90s or late 80s but not sure about that.

This is probably Ride the Bullet The description on wiki and IMDB don't really go into the same detail but having seen the movie I can say that it's very similar to what you have described. In particular the ghost driving him, the amusement park and the boys mother in the hospital.
